# How can you make space between images?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

[image]

How can I make space between the images? (if you hover a image it will show some text, I dont know if that will make some differents)

cs:

```
.row1{
float:left; 
padding: 30px;


}
.row2{
float:left; 
padding: 30px;

}
.row3{
float:left; 
padding: 30px;


}
```

from up and down.

Row1: images on the left side

Row2: images in the middle

Row3: images on the right side

```
       <div class="row1">
          <h3>Track/spots</h3>  
         <div id="wrapper">
             <img src="producten/banaan.jpg" alt="large luxe beach"  width="300" height="200" class="hover" />
                   <p class="text">Banaan Spot <br> Prijs: vanaf &euro;58,75 </p>
             </div>

             <div id="wrapper">
             <img src="producten/track.jpg"   width="300" height="200"class="hover" />
               <p class="text">Track Rail, Track Light <br> Aansluiting: 3 fase rail <br> Prijs: vanaf &euro;64,95 <br> Kleur: 3000K / 4000K</p>
                  </div>

            <div id="wrapper">
            <img src="producten/led.jpg" width="300" height="200" class="hover" />
               <p class="text">MR 16 spot <br> Aansluting: GU10 / GU5.3<br> Voltage: 12V | 230V<br> Prijs: vanaf &euro;5,95<br>Kleur: 2500K / / 2700K / 3000K / 4000K </p>
             </div>
        </div>

           <div class="row2">
          <h3>Ledstrip</h3>
                <div id="wrapper">
            <img src="producten/lestrip.jpg" alt="large luxe beach"  width="300" height="200" class="hover" />
                   <p class="text">Ledstrip, SMD 5050, SMD 2835, RGB <br>Voltage: 12V / 24V<br> Prijs: vanaf &euro;8,95 </p></div>
         <div id="wrapper">
            <img src="producten/kleur.jpg" width="300" height="200" class="hover" />
                   <p class="text"></p></div>
         <div id="wrapper">
            <img src="producten/profiel.jpg"   width="300" height="200" class="hover" />
   <p class="text"></p></div>


        </div>
               <div class="row3">

          <h3>Panelen</h3>   
                    <div id="wrapper">
            <img src="producten/panel2.jpg" alt="large luxe beach" width="300" height="200" class="hover" /> 
                   <p class="text">Rond Paneel<br> Aansluting: N.V.T.<br>Wattage: 6W / 15W / 18 / 20W / 24W<br>Prijs: vanaf &euro;21,95</p></div>
                   <div id="wrapper">
            <img src="producten/panel.jpg"  width="300" height="200" class="hover" />
               <p class="text">Vierkant Paneel<br> Aansluting: N.V.T.<br>Wattage: 36W / 40W / 42W<br>Voltage: 230V<br>Prijs: vanaf &euro;34,95<br>Kleur: 3000K / 4000K</p></div>
                    <div id="wrapper">
            <img src="producten/rechthoek.jpg"   width="300" height="200" class="hover" />
   <p class="text"></p>
        </div>
          </div>
```

**I tried it with margin but it didnt work**

Comment: Why do you set the height of the wrapper to be at least 20% more than the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all those divs with the `id="wrapper"` add a class `img-wrapper` with the following properties:

```
.img-wrapper{
  height:400px; //Just to set an example.
  margin:5%;
}
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper" class="img-wrapper">
            <img src="producten/profiel.jpg"   width="300" height="200" class="hover" />
   <p class="text"></p></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give parent div, **margin** value.

Answer (score 0):

The best bet is to use the `visibility` property of CSS, [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/visibility)

From the docs "**The visibility property can be used to hide an element while leaving the space where it would have been. It can also hide rows or columns of a table**"

Made a small fiddle which will kinda  fit the scenario.

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/luciferous/w0z12jru/)

Set the initial value to hidden and toggle using appropriate CSS selectors when hovering . For eg:

```
p {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.content:hover+p{
  visibility:visible;
}
```